Given a lax monoidal endofunctor in Set how do you turn it into a monad?
If I construct a monad (endofunctor: T, unit, join) on Set (objects: A,B, Cartesian product: x), I get a monoidal product, ⊗: T(A) x T(B) -> T(A x B), but I don't have direct control as to what it looks like. For my applications, it would be useful to define the monoidal product myself and then define an extra operation that gives me a monad because the details of join aren’t as important to me as the details of the monoidal product.
I think I can get a monad from a lax monoidal endofunctor in Set by defining a co-bi-strength,
T^2(A x B) -> T(A) x T(B),
but getting a join operation from there is convoluted, and I haven’t checked the coherence conditions. Is there a standard way to add an operation to a lax monoidal endofunctor in Set and get a monad?
Here’s a related question/answer that asks something of the reverse question: given monad on Set, why is it also a monoidal functor? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306514/what-makes-every-strong-monad-on-a-certain-category-be-a-monoidal-functor.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think every monoidal functor in Sett is a monad. The multidimensional array functor comes to mind. There is no join.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, that’s right. A monad on set is a monoidal functor, but a monoidal functor needs extra structure to be a monad. I’m asking how to add that extra structure if I already have a monoidal functor. I still want a monad in the end, but I want greater control over the monoidal product than the usual construction

Well if you have co-bi-strength you can define a monad (I think) but that functor doesn't seem have it either. I'm not sure you can add such an additional structure at will. Have to think about it...

I am still very confused by this question. If you want a monad, add monad operations. Do you want the monad and lax monoidal structures to agree in some way?

@NaïmFavier Yes, I'd like the monoidal binary product from the monad to be the same as the one I define

I don't think it's possible.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Oh that's too bad. Can you explain why? I thought I could get there with the co-bi-strength. Does that fail to produce a monad?

Can't you use T(A) × T(B) -> T (A × B)?
